# Laravel 5.2 project, Move from Local to server

Tags: laravel, upload

Im trying to uplaod my laravel project from local to server.. But while uploading, i got this error

> "Unknown Bytes complete FAILED! :The file you uploaded, contains a
>   virus so the upload was canceled:
>   Atomicorp.Zip.File.Contains.bat.UNOFFICIAL FOUND"

What is "Atomicorp" ?

Comment: @ujwal  As a zip file

Comment: Try this solution : http://cpanelstuffs.linuxcabin.com/?p=833

Comment: @Mr. Engineer   Thank u :)  i"ll go through it.

Comment: Did u unzipped? after upload

Comment: @ujwal dhakal ,  No, the uploaded file just get disappears after uplaod

Comment: Which server are you on? Please provide with the sever details

Comment: I am also facing the same issue